# Spell checker for non-English languages in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spell-checking

I am trying to find a **Spell Checker in Python** which can be used in different languages apart from English, I am specially interested in **Portuguese**. By doing my research, the best I have found so far is the Bing Spell Check API for Python, by Microsoft.

However, to use it you need an Azure account in order to get the keys. I was wondering if there exists any other alternative where I can get the spell check with its suggestions by free. So far I have found `PyEnchant`
 library, but it is out-of-date, and `autocorrection` library, which only supports English language.

I have also found **Peter Norvig's code**, but I was wondering if there is any other implementation for spell checking that have been tested in other languages.

Comment: What is wrong with [hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) with its [pyhunspell](https://github.com/blatinier/pyhunspell) module, given the Portugese [dictionary](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/hunspell-dict-pt-PT)?

Comment: @Guidot, how can I download the Portuguese dictionary? The link provided is not giving it And thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Found something [here](http://natura.di.uminho.pt/download/TGZ/Dictionaries/hunspell/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing Spell Check API has a free tier with limited # calls and TPS: https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.CognitiveServicesBingSpellCheck-v7. Select the F0 tier.